# Remove command is not working in context of index-filter

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I am trying to remove a directory from the git repo. I have run the following command:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter --prune-empty "git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch -- wwwroot/Themes/_Backup"
```

Git is complaining as follows:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch -- wwwroot/Themes/_Backup': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I am using `--` to separate paths from revisions, and I know that `wwwroot/Themes/_Backup` exists. Further, I have successfully run the following command:

```
git rm -rf --cached --ignore-unmatch -- wwwroot/Themes/_Backup
```

Why isn't that command working in the context of `--index-filter`?

Answer (score 0):

No option may come *between* the `--index-filter` option and its `<command>`. In my case, I was sticking the `--prune-empty` option there.

**This Works**

```
git filter-branch --prune-empty --index-filter <command>
```

**This Works**

```
git filter-branch --index-filter <command> --prune-empty
```

**This Fails**

```
git filter-branch --index-filter --prune-empty <command>
```

Answer (score -1):

You're trying to remove a directory from history of a Git repo, and there's an easier way to do this than using `git filter-branch`. Use the [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), a simpler, faster alternative specifically designed for removing files and folders from Git history.

Carefully follow the [usage instructions](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#usage) - the core bit is just this: download the [BFG jar](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#download) (requires Java 6 or above) and run this command:

```
$ java -jar bfg.jar --delete-folders _Backup  my-repo.git
```

Your entire repository history will be scanned, and folder named `_Backup` will be removed.

*Full disclosure: I'm the author of the BFG Repo-Cleaner.*

Comment: You could improve the answer by answering the question instead of offering an alternative technique.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ShaunLuttin! As your question started with 'I am trying to remove a directory from the git repo', I took the liberty of trying to help you with that goal, which was a mistake.